# what is the syntax for selecting multiple picklist values using ISPICKVAL?

Tags: formula, picklist

I want to know what is the correct formula syntax for selecting multiple picklist values? For example `

> and(isblank(First_Submitted__c),ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Submitted,Awaiting Recontract,Won Re-Contract"))

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in using the OR statement with ISPICKVAL. For each picklist value I want to check for I need to seperate with an OR.

> and(isblank(Custom_Field_*c),OR( 
>   (ISPICKVAL(FieldA*_c, "Value1")),(ISPICKVAL(FieldA_*c, "Value2")),(ISPICKVAL(FieldA*_c,"Value3"))))